# 'SqlConnection' could not be found in Azure DevOps's build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a .NET core app that references the `System.Data.SqlClient library` and its dependencies. Building the project locally it works without problems but, when I build it in an Azure DevOps's pipeline, it returns many "not found" errors about that library.

These are the errors:

```
Helpers\MicrosoftSQLServerHelper.cs(15,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\src\Visyon.ETLs.Executors\Visyon.ETLs.Executors.csproj]
Helpers\MicrosoftSQLServerHelper.cs(19,42): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SqlCommand' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\src\Visyon.ETLs.Executors\Visyon.ETLs.Executors.csproj]
Helpers\MicrosoftSQLServerHelper.cs(29,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\src\Visyon.ETLs.Executors\Visyon.ETLs.Executors.csproj]
Helpers\MicrosoftSQLServerHelper.cs(43,42): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SqlCommand' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\src\Visyon.ETLs.Executors\Visyon.ETLs.Executors.csproj]
Helpers\MicrosoftSQLServerHelper.cs(55,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\src\Visyon.ETLs.Executors\Visyon.ETLs.Executors.csproj]
Helpers\MicrosoftSQLServerHelper.cs(59,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SqlBulkCopy' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\src\Visyon.ETLs.Executors\Visyon.ETLs.Executors.csproj]
```

I've checked what command is launch by Azure DevOps to build the project (`"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build d:\a\1\s\src\Visyon.ETLs\Visyon.ETLs.csproj --configuration Release`) and I've launched on my local machine. Locally, it works.

Also, I use the default .NET core build template provided by Azure DevOps and run the build on the agent "VS2017".

Can someone help me?

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> 'SqlConnection' could not be found in Azure DevOps's build

According to the error message, it seems you are missing the reference `System.Data.SqlClient` when you build with Azure DevOps. You should add two nuget tasks to restore the package `System.Data.SqlClient`:

[NuGet Tool Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/nuget?view=azure-devops)

[Restore NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops#restore-nuget-packages)

When we build the project/solution on local machine, the packages is downloaded stored in the `\packages` folder, this folder is ignored by the source control when we submit our source code(This is recommended.), so when we build the project/solution on the  Azure DevOps, we need add nuget restore task to restore nuget package before we build it:

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.